# Cron not working properly in Continuum Environment

Tags: continuum

I configured a Cron Expression in Continuum Environment.It works fine but suddenly now it stopped working

```
 runs at 9 am EDT every day     0 0 9 ? * *
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically some information will be logged in `continuum.log` that indicates any changes to the schedule. If the scheduler stopped working it may require Continuum to be restarted. If it continues not to work after restarting the configuration may not be stored correctly and need to be reset.